# match() versus %in% operator

Tags: r, match

From what I read in `?match()`

> "%in%" <- function(x, table) match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0

Why do I get a different result using `match(x, dict[["word"]], 0L)`

```
vapply(strsplit(df$text, " "), 
   function(x) sum(dict[["score"]][match(x, dict[["word"]], 0L)]), 1)
#[1]  2 -2  3 -2
```

Versus when using `dict[["word"]] %in% x`

```
vapply(strsplit(df$text, " "), 
       function(x) sum(dict[["score"]][dict[["word"]] %in% x]), 1)
#[1]  2 -2  1 -1
```

**Data**

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data_frame(text = c("I love pandas", "I hate monkeys", 
                          "pandas pandas pandas", "monkeys monkeys"))
dict <- data_frame(word = c("love", "hate", "pandas", "monkeys"),
                   score = c(1,-1,1,-1))
```

**Update**

After Richard's explanation, I now understand my initial misconception. The `%in%` operator returns a logical vector:

```
> sapply(strsplit(df$text, " "), function(x) dict[["word"]] %in% x)
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

And `match()` returns location numbers:

```
> sapply(strsplit(df$text, " "), function(x) match(x, dict[["word"]], 0L))
[[1]]
[1] 0 1 3

[[2]]
[1] 0 2 4

[[3]]
[1] 3 3 3

[[4]]
[1] 4 4
```

Comment: `match()` returns  location numbers, which may be more than 1, `%in%` is a logical vector where a match (TRUE) is **always** 1.  Hence, the sums can differ

Comment: Got it. I should have read the documentation more thoroughly. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot the `> 0` part of the function.

Comment: @RichardScriven might as well move that to an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`match()` returns an integer vector of positions for the first match, which will be greater 1 if that position is not the first.

`%in%` returns a logical vector where a match (TRUE) is **always** 1 (when represented as an integer).

Hence, the sums in your calculations will likely differ.